# AWS Lambda caching DynamoDB response

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having difficulty with understanding behaviour of AWS Lambda that works with DynamoDB. My Lambda is doing relatively simple task:

1. Query DynamoDB for one specific value
2. Increment that value in Lambda
3. Store incremented value in same DynamoDB record

In most cases it works well but in situation that one execution happens just after another is finished (e.g. second execution starts few seconds after first execution is finished), both executions returns same value from DynamoDB (instead second execution returning result of first execution)

If my explanation is not clear let me share example:

1. First lambda execution query DynamoDB for value X which is 5 at the
   moment
2. First lambda execution increments X from 5 to 6 First lambda
   execution stores X with value 6 to DynamoDB
3. First lambda execution
   finishes successfully
4. Second lambda execution starts after few
   seconds
5. Second lambda execution query DynamoDB for value X which is
   5 at the moment (and I expect it to be 6 since first lambda
   execution has finished successfully before second execution has been
   started)

Can you please advice what can be the reason of such behaviour. No errors are thrown in lambda, everything works correctly if executions are separated by longer time (e.g. minute or two), in CloudWatch I see clearly that one execution is finished before second is started.

Perhaps there is some kind of caching mechanism in Lambda or DynamoDB that remembers last DynamoDB response and resend it to Lambda if same query is executed (even though underneath data has been modified in the mean time)? The hint behind "caching idea" is because second lambda execution is significantly faster than first one (first takes ~1s, second ~200 ms)

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: read about [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and [read consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) and [lamda cold start](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/)

Comment: @IłyaBursov race condition is not the case since from logs it's clear that two executions are not happening same (or partially same) time. However I missed read consistency topic and it acctually may be it. Unfortunetly I see I can't switch to strongly consistent reads since queries are using GSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be due to eventual consistency of ddb table data, as you already realised GSI query doesn't support strong consistency read of ddb, to enforce strong consistency you must modify your code/query to query the X value in strong consistent way. Moreover to ensure there is no race situation as the lambda functions can overwrite the X with each other, optimistic locking mechanism also need to be implemented (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html)

I would suggest the lambda function implemented as below:

1. Query the X value from the ddb table directly (instead of from GSI), using ddb strong consistency read. (e.g. = 5)
2. The lambda do its thing and increment X from 5 to 6.
3. Issue a ddb conditional write of ddb table on X to 6, with condition X = 5. Check if updated item count = 1, if not throw an error.

Notice that the other process that call the lambda need to have a retry logics in-placed if case there is race condition. But the overall process guarantee data consistency.